# How-to ensure consistent legend when using PieChart?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, legending

**Description:**

I would like to enforce consistent legend and style throughout dynamic `PieChart` evaluation.

**Problem:**

Based on current implementation, the color and legend associated with particular datasets switch throughout evaluation.

**Example:**

```
DynamicModule[
 {n = 20},
 Column[{
   Row[{Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}],
   Dynamic[
    PieChart[#[[All, 2]], ChartLegends -> #[[All, 1]], 
       ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}] & @ 
     Tally @RandomChoice[{True, False}, n]]
   }]
 ]
```

**Output:**

[image: output1]
[image: output2]
[image: output3]

How could I enforce `Legend` to include both `True` and `False`; where `True` to be always represented in `Green` and `False` in `Red`? I would also like `True` to come before `False` in the `Legend`.

Comment: If you do `Sort@Tally@RandomChoice...` it'll sort the values first and won't have this problem.

Comment: @N.J.Evans partially, it does. There is however another issue which is related to the question. Please let me edit OP.

Comment: Use `trueFalseTally[list_] := {#, Count[list, #]} & /@ {True, False};` instead of `Tally` It will return {{True,numTrues},{False,numFalses}}` even if there aren't any, then your plot will format correctly.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Appreciate that, leave your answer.  I will leave the question open for some time to see what people think. If there is no other solutions, I will be happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{n = 20}, 
 Column[{Row[{Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}], 
   Dynamic[Legended[PieChart[Thread[Style[#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1]] /.
        {True -> Red, False -> Green}] ], 
      ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}] &@ 
      Tally@RandomChoice[{True, False}, n], 
     SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, {False, True}]]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively (thanks: Brett Champion):

```
DynamicModule[{n = 20}, 
 Column[{Row[{Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}], 
   Dynamic[PieChart[Thread[Style[#[[All, 2]], #[[All, 1]] /. 
                      {True -> Red, False -> Green}]], 
       ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, {False, True}]] &@
     Tally@RandomChoice[{True, False}, n]]}]]
```

Comment: You can also pass the SwatchLegend to ChartLegends: `ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, {True, False}]`

Comment: This fails in the case that n=1 and RandomChoice returns True. Since `Tally` only returns an entry for True, your `ChartStyle` applies `Green` to the `True` value, even though the legend is correct.

Comment: I think *all* the code should be checked carefully as to whether green is true or false...

Comment: @N.J.Evans, thank you. I will update with a fix.

Comment: @Brett and N.J. Evans, thank you for the comments. I hope the updated version fixes the issue you mention.

Answer (score 4):

The `Red/Green` problem stems from the fact that `Tally` returns tallied values in the order each element is first encountered, and the other issue is because `Tally` doesn't return a `0` entry for elements not in the list. Both issues can be solved with a custom tally:

`explicitTally[list_,toTally_List] := {#, Count[list, #]} & /@ toTally;`

If you use `explicitTally[#,{True,False}]` in place of `Tally` everything should work correctly. Use is shown below, I also used `Transpose` and `Apply (@@)` to clean it up a little.

```
DynamicModule[
 {n = 20},
 Column[{
   Row[{
     Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 100, 1}],
     Dynamic[n]
     }],
   Dynamic[
    PieChart[
       #2,
       ChartLegends -> #1,
       ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}
       ] & @@ 
     Transpose@
      explicitTally[RandomChoice[{True, False}, n], {True, False}]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```